# CSS - Where does my white space come from?

Tags: html, css, safari

Ok its the same old game: I am creating a wordpress theme for a client, everything works fine so far (work in progress), but below my footer there is some white space, which source I cannot detect.

Maybe I am blind. I have used firebug to delete every `div` or `ul` or `li` step by step to find its source, but it did not help.

Where does this problem come from?

[image: Preview Image]

[Preview site for CSS / HTML information](http://spd.marianrick.de)

The only possible source I did found in firebug is this `user-agent-style-sheet`, while its last three lines appear to be inactive (low grey font color while the rest is black):

```
body {
- User-Agent-Style-Sheet
display: block;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Displaying in Safari 8.0.3

**// Prebens solution explained:**

I have used clearfixes to make sure my `float: left/right` styles never mess up my layout. The used clearfix uses `::after` to create an clearing element:

```
.clearfix::after {
content: ".";
clear: both;
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
height: 0px;
}
```

I did use this clearfix for my `footer` (bottom of my side) as well, because of that after my footer the `clearfix` did create an element with `content: "."` which resulted in the whitespace. Changing my `::after content` into `content: " "` did solve the problem and works fine just as well.

Comment: That's interesting, from a quick glance, it actually looks like the space is even below the html-element, don't see where it could be coming from though.

Comment: The HTML being styled (or rather, a minimal example of HTML+CSS  that reproduces the problem) should be included in the question, rather than just linked to.

Comment: @cHao I agree, but because I had no idea where this error came from, it was quite hard to offer an excerpt of my code. Its not like one html element caused this error and I thought about it being a browser agent error, thats why I chose to post the full site!

Comment: @MarianRick: So, take the HTML and CSS from a page that exhibits the issue, and save it.  Then start removing stuff.  View it in a browser, and see if it's still messed up.  Repeat til you've removed all you can remove without the problem going away.  (Fun part is, this isn't just a good idea for SO questions, it's a problem-solving skill in itself -- in the process of trimming down the code, quite often you'll find the problem yourself.)

Comment: The problem with linking to your site, is that presumably your goal is to fix it.  So the link will lead to a fixed site, and future readers don't get to see the original problem firsthand.

Comment: @cHao your absolutely right. Thats why I did comment Prebens fix with a short explanation. But I understand, that there are better ways to create a good platform, so I added an explanation to my own answer as well. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
footer.clearfix:after {
content: "";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Of course using a clearfix with  `clearfix: after {content: "."}` was the mistake I did not see! You really did help me out, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. The `content:"(some)";` has tricked me more than once ;-)